# what does 나가거든 mean here?? kim young ha short story

Tags: vocabulary

here is the sentence

이렇게 만난 것도 인연인데 [[ 나가거든]] 커피나 한 잔 하지요,라고 말을 건네보았지만 여자
는 묵묵부답이었다.

I know what 거든 means when you use it to emphasize what you're saying but in this sentence it seems like a different usage...
thank you for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to the **[NAVER Korean Dictionary](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=1406500)**:

### 거든

*ending*.

1. A connective ending indicating *"If something is true"*, *"If something comes true"*.

   - 그분을 **만나거든** 꼭 제 인사 말씀을 전해 주세요. 
      **If** you **meet** him, please send my greetings to him.
   - 할아버지가 **편찮으시거든** 내게 꼭 기별을 해라. 
      **If** grandpa gets **sick**, be sure to contact me.
   - 혹시 길이 **미끄럽거든** 지하철을 이용해라. 
      **If** the road is **slippery**, use the subway.

(continued)

---

Also refer to the **Standard Korean Rules**(표준어 규정):

**Standard Korean Rules Chapter 2, Section 4, Clause 17**.

'거든' is used after the verb stem or prefinal endings such as '-았-','-겠', '-시-' to indicate the meaning of assumption, condition, reason, or resolution. It also has the nuance of "If we can think of something as true, it becoming a cause or reason, other thing can also be thought as true without doubt." An ending with a similar pronunciation '-거던' is also being used, but we choose '-거든' to be the only standard form.

**표준어 규정 2장 4절 17항**.

‘-거든’은 동사 어간이나 선어말어미 ‘-았-,-겠-,-시-’ 아래에 쓰여 가정이나 조건, 이유나 다짐의 뜻을 나타내고, 어떤 사실을 인정함으로써 그것이 원인이나 근거가 되어 다른 사실이 당연히 인정됨을 나타내거나 이상하거나 납득할 수 없다는 느낌을 나타내기도 하는 어미이다. 비슷한 발음의 ‘-거던’이 사용되기도 하나 ‘거든’만 표준어로 삼는다.

---

So '-거든' can be translated to *if*, *when*, or *provided that*. Hence we can translate the given sentence to:

> Meeting like this is destiny, so **if(when) we leave here** let's have some coffee. 
>   이렇게 만난 것도 인연인데 **나가거든** 커피나 한 잔 하지요.